# Where to call django.setup?

Tags: python, django

I use django_cleanup and wonder what is django.setup() Do I call it in settings?
When I call apps.get_models() I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

Answer (score 0):

As you may read in official documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#initialization-process , django.setup() is method which reads settings, and configure you project, so you may easly use your models.